# Flying Insect Identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What insect is this?

[image]

Found in the UK, approximately 10mm-15mm in length.

Comment: That is clearly a mayfly (family: Ephemeroptera) — using that may help you find an answer for yourself. It would also be very helpful if you were to [edit] your post to include "as much information as possible on location/habitat, size/characteristics and behavior." (*from the species-identification tag description*) ——— In particular, what is the local environment is like and can you give more specific location information than "UK"?

Comment: if you want to learn more about this group of insects you can take a look here https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/ephemeroptera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That insect looks quite like a Mayfly, it's an ancient insect that belongs to the order [Ephemeroptera](https://ucmp.berkeley.edu/arthropoda/uniramia/ephemeroptera.html). I'll go a step further and guess that species, that one there is most probably a Green drake, they aren't harmful at all as in they don't sting or bite but if a lot of dead mayflies pile up they can cause respiratory inflamations, asthma, hay fever that sort of stuff.

They're a vital part of the pond ecosystem.[image: Credit to Missoulian Angler] Here's a picture of a Green drake and it's quite similar to your picture. Credit to Missoulian Angler
I think some of the major reasons why it is a Mayfly are a s follows:-

1. The transparent wings are a minor giveaway.
2. The three tail filaments are a major giveaway.
3. Very short almost non-existent antennae

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Thank you for taking the [tour], but you may also wish to consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you!

Comment: There friend, added a picture.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Please provide a citation/source for the image you are using — images must be credited to their creators just like [quotes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) are to their authors. This is generally considered good practice in scientific communication and will help other users understand by providing context. ——— In addition, it would be very helpful if you could describe the key features that allow you to be certain this is a mayfly and what makes you suspect a Green drake in particular. Thanks again!

Comment: There mate edited as you said I should, I think that should put me in the clear. Grateful for your sound advice